# Regular expression generation for a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to create a regular expression to check the following string pattern, I tried following these tutorials but it's still confusing. Any help is appreciated.

**Type: In Folder**

(T or t)**ype**(spaces or no space)**:**(spaces or no space)(i or I)**n**(spaces or multiple space)(f or F)**older**

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: `^[Tt]ype\s*:\s*[Ii]n\s+[Ff]older$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following your desired pattern at the end of your question:

`(t|T)ype\s*:\s*(i|I)n\s*(f|F)older`

The above pattern should match your string. Mind you, `\s*` is zero to unlimited spaces, which means it would match on the string you provided even if there were no spaces present; if there will always be at least one space present, you can replace them with `\s+`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

(T|t)ype\s*:\s*(I|i)n\s*(f|F)older